# My VBA Excel function works when called by a test function but consitently fails when called from sheet another function that is a embedded in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Sub addtoMA(dbPrice As Double, dbRow As Double, sh As Worksheet)
Dim s As Long   'for bitshifting the array
Const colstosave = 50
Dim rn As Range, intPrice() As Variant
deActsheet  'stop events and other annoyance
On Error GoTo catch
If dbRow = 0 Then
    'MsgBox "row number missing in addtoma"
    GoTo finally
End If
Set rn = sh.Range("At" & dbRow & ":cQ" & dbRow) 'the row
intPrice() = rn 'the  array
   ' shift elements one position right- e.g. arr 99 moves to arr 100
   For s = colstosave To 2 Step -1
        If intPrice(1, s - 1) <> "" Then
            intPrice(1, s) = intPrice(1, s - 1)
        Else
            intPrice(1, s) = 0
        End If
   Next s
intPrice(1, 1) = dbPrice 'current price

    rn = intPrice() 'store the array

finally:
Set rn = Nothing


  actSheet 'allow events and other annoyance
 Exit Sub
catch:

  'MsgBox Err.Description
  Debug.Print ""
  GoTo finally
End Sub
```

The code above runs perfectly when I call form the immediate window with:
addtoMA 5,9,sheetpointer

in integration it is called by a function that is embedded as a formula.
The parameters the are receibed are identical I double checked this.
`rn.rows` and `rn.columns.count` are exactly the same dimensions as
`ubound(intprice,1)` and `ubound(intprice,2`)

Yet every time it is called from the sheet it fails with

> Application-defined or object-defined error

I could just use a database, but I cant be beaten by this.

Any ideas?
It just generates a few moving averages for a bot

Comment: A function called from the worksheet can only effect the value of the cell that calls the UDF.  So you cannot return the modified array back to the range with a UDF

Comment: `deActsheet  'stop events and other annoyance` -- a UDF can't toggle global application state.

Comment: Thanks Scott, You have misread. The UDF calls the function you see above and the unction above reads in the range changes it and writes it back. I guess it is in the same call stack but its not executed by a UDF.
If what you say is true, would writing to a database also be a problem. I have had excel calling a Machine learning stored procedure i sql server in the past so I a bit confused. I suppose SQL server is a server and excel is a file?

Comment: I'd better find some reliable docs on what exactly you can do with a udf. If all this is true they are pretty hopeless on the face of it.

Comment: Ok Thanks for the pointers. Spot on.
I have had to abandon using the sheet and go with in memeory global array. Much more complex because of a number of sheets in the workbook. Had to reduce the size of data types and number stored because the stack is very small likely to overflow.
Seems to work OK now